# How can I add multiple numbers in to one cell while checking its related condition?

Tags: excel

My problem is like, I want to add a few numbers while checking the condition in corresponding cell in MS-Excel. e.g.

```
    A    B   C
   ==== === ===
1  YES  100 300
2  NO   100
3  YES  100
4  ABC  100
5  XYZ  100
6  YES  100
```

Here I want to check condition in A column and if it is "YES" add corresponding column B otherwise don't add. Complete result may be shown in cell "C1". So that "C1" may have result 300.

Comment: Wait, where do you get 200 for C1?

Comment: Do you only have 6 rows you're working with, exactly as you've shown, or can the number of rows vary?

Comment: This is just an example. Rows can be like 100+. There are three "YES" so I just want to add numbers that have string value "YES". C1 is just another cell on excel sheet. This can be any other like C5, D20 or any other.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMIF() like this in cell C1:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A6,"=YES",B1:B6)
```

Tested:

[image]